# many massages from socket cause thread blocking

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, websocket, socket.io

I have a socket connection which implemented with socket.io which send 2 type of events.
if browser receives event A, angularjs runs a function and then inserts a row to table A which takes about 100 ms, and if browser receives event B angularjs runs a function and then inserts a row to table B which takes about 150 ms.

now imaging server is transmitting an event per 10 ms, it causes thread blocking and browser freezes so i can not do any thing else.

what is the best practice to solve these kind of problems.

Comment: Why would you create 100 rows a second? Your app will run out of memory in a few seconds,

Comment: i am deleting last row when new row arrives and only show last 20 rows but table should get updated

Comment: I would throttle this so it renders only every second or so

Comment: please check the right bottom table in this link
https://www.binance.com/en/trade/BTC_USDT?theme=dark&type=spot

my application is something like this not an exchange but my table should be updated like this

Comment: i am using angularjs should i change to react or vue or this is the javascript problem? if it is javascript problem so how did they solve it?

Comment: you can insert the row asynchronously by using promise and also refresh the page only after some time by limiting rate.

Comment: @SinaNouri rows aren't added to the table, only the text and classes change, that makes a huge difference. You can try to do an update in `requestAnimationFrame` loop